# @azure/msal-angular logout redirects to app but app does not show

Tags: angular, authentication, azure-ad-msal

When logging off, the redirect back to the web app url works and the browser console shows messages from the app indicating the app bootstrapped correctly however, the screen is stuck on https://login.microsoftonline.com with the message "Hang on a moment whilst we log you out". The message changes after 5 seconds to "Hmm... we're having trouble signing you out. You may still be signed in to some applications. Close your browser to finish signing out.".

My app is rendered inside another iframe rather than at the top level, but I don't think I'm able to influence this; I just call msal.logout() with no args. In case my config is amiss, I've included it below.

(page)
https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/logoutsession

(iframe)
https://login.live.com/logout.srf?iframed_by=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com

(iframe)
https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0

(iframe)
https://iant8-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/logged-out?sid=(a-guid)

I've tried
- fiddler running and not running
- chrome 71 / firefox 64

My msal config is

```
export const msalConfiguration: MsalConfig = {
  clientID: '<guid>',
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<guid>',
  redirectUri: 'https://iant8-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/redirect',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://iant8-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/logged-out',
  logger: msalLogger,
  consentScopes: ['user.read'],
  isAngular: true,
  protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
  piiLoggingEnabled: true
}
```

I can't get the sample app working either with the same error at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular/samples/MSALAngularDemoApp to work either (dev branch, commit ac32c459c7398be02fe3f50afbd7d38e19d8ef0e).

Comment: Can't see any issues with your config. Your can try ending your postLogoutRedirectUri with a '/', but it shouldn't make a difference. I have a strong suspicion that there is an error being swallowed in the Msal Library - try putting a debugger in the logout function of msal.js.

Comment: I compared the logout implementation. In both cases it delegates down to the msal.js UserAgentApplication's logout method which are identical.

Comment: I did some more testing. My gmail account does not logout as described. I invited my work email and that does successfully logout. My azure subscription is owned by my gmail account, which is a user type "member" in my default active directory. My work email is a "guest" in my default active directory.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this...?